# как сделать в radiolist по умолчанию ничего не выбрано

Tags: php, yii2, activeform

по умолчанию выбран первый,нужно чтобы пользователь сам ставил флажок,чтобы по умолчанию было ничего не выбрано

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'for_small_business')->radioList([
                0 =>'СМП',
                1 => 'без СМП'
 ] )?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, у вас `$model->for_small_business` содержит значение `0`. Попробуйте по умолчанию поставить `null`